# Linking to unity mobile app from facebook open graph post

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

At the moment, if someone clicks on an open graph post made by my app, it goes to the URL of the object. I would like to send the user to the iOS or Android app depending on what platform they see the Open Graph post. My app does not have a canvas version. I looked into AppLinks but I can't seem to find any documentation on an end to end example for Unity. Is there any way to reliably redirect the user to your app from an Open Graph post?